# Find comments with no reply either by vote or comment by current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

## Overview

I have a list of comments where the current_user can either reply with a new comment or vote for the comment. Now i'm trying to create a view **to force** the user to reply with a new comment or just vote for the comment.

## Task

Find comments with no reply (vote or comment) by current_user.

### Models

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent,  class_name: 'Comment', optional: true
  has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Vote Model**

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

## Question

Is this possible with a decent performance to create an activerecord query for that? Or would it be easier to create a record every time a user creates a comment in a new table like **pending_replies** or something like that and then delete on creation of reply?

Any hints and starting points would be **amazing**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be too bad, easy to understand.

```
# user.rb

# Rails 4
def comments_with_no_vote_or_reply
  Comment.where.not(:id => votes.pluck(:comment_id) + replies.pluck(:parent_id))
end

# Rails 3
def comments_with_no_vote_or_reply
  Comment.where("comments.id not in (?)", votes.pluck(:comment_id) + replies.pluck(:parent_id))
end
```